# Decoding Airplay Packets in Java or C/C++ on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, airplay

I'm currently working on an AirPlay receiver for a subpart of an android application. I am using the following framework:

https://github.com/pentateu/DroidAirPlay

While this works great on some mid range devices such as the miPad, we need to get this running on a low spec custom device. The custom device is decoding the airplay packets at 10x to 20x slower than the miPad. As a result, the audio packets lose time synchronisation and due to the time taken to decode the packets, the audio can never re-sync.

I was looking into some other airplay receiver apps on the Play Store and from what I can see they tend to be based on Shairport (https://github.com/abrasive/shairport) for the airplay receiver side of things.

**Note: ** the Shairport based frameworks do not seem to suffer the synchronisation issue on the low end device.

The framework I am using is heavily based on the Shairport framework apart from that it is written in Java.

For decoding data, is C/C++ far superior than Java?

If so, would directing the decoding part of the DroidAirPlay framework via a C or C++ implementation using the NDK give me a large boost to performance?

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that Java compiles to bytecode that runs in a virtual machine, it may not necessarily be slower (or faster) than a natively compiled executable, whether C/C++ or not. It all depends on the program!

There's a number of reasons why in this case Java may be slower:

- The decoding implementation might just be poorly coded/optimized? (which isn't really Java's fault)
- The Java compiler may generate sub-optimal code for the JVM.
- Some of Java's language constructs are just too slow for the speed/resource demands placed on it here.
- The JVM just is another abstraction layer and the culprit
- The garbage collection is in on it?!

(I have to note here that I'm not an expert on Java!)

However, I still wouldn't go so far as to call Java *intrinsically slower* than C or C++. I'm sure you can find [many-a benchmarks](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org) and tests on the internet comparing one language to another, and some make claims to a certain degree (out of pride and ego?). But those tests are *only* specific cases, usually testing *specific aspects* of a larger language (hash-map lookup performance for instance!).

LLVM had a [three part blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) on C and why undefined behavior allows the compiler to generate still correct but more efficient code at the cost of inferring run-time safety checking or deciding that i+1 *always* comes after i, totally ignoring the existence of integer overflow. If the programmer is not careful, this can have disastrous consequences.

In the words of Bjarne himself in *[Abstraction and the C++ machine model](http://www.stroustrup.com/abstraction-and-machine.pdf)*:

> C++ was designed to be a systems programming language and has been used for
>   embedded systems programming and other resource-constrained types of
>   programming since the earliest days.

As such, I believe C and C++ can be pushed further than Java because of this undefined behavior and less restrictions placed on it. (And there's also the inline assembly bit, but that's not strictly C!)